# Is there any animation that illustrates the "fold" and "unfold" operations of convolutional layers?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, pytorch, convolution, resource-request, convolutional-layers

There are [fourteen convolution layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#convolution-layers) in PyTorch. Among them six are related to convolution, another six are related to transposed convolution. The remaining two are [fold](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unfold.html#torch.nn.Unfold) and [unfold](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unfold.html#torch.nn.Unfold) operations.

The documentation of PyTorch itself provided [this link](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic/blob/master/README.md) in order to visualize the operations to understand the convolution and transposed convolution easily. You can see the visuals and understand those variants of convolution operation easily.

Are there any such visuals (e.g. a diagram or animation) or any other resources available to visualize and understand the remaining two operations: fold and unfold?

Comment: https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/